# Kendo grid cancel edit loses icon on custom command button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

In addition to the standard edit/delete buttons I have a custom command button defined in a kendo grid:

```
{ name: "submit", text: " ", visible: "isSubmitable", click: submitItem }
```

The button is assigned an icon on databind:

```
$(".k-grid-submit").prepend("<span class='k-icon k-i-redo' style='color: blue'></span>");
```

But if I click the edit button and then cancel, the custom button loses its icon. One workaround [suggested by a Telerik Admin](https://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-command-icon-disappears#RYWei4V-4kqbKImt8J1pRw) is to refresh the datasource on the cancel event. This works but is ridiculous, particularly for large datasets, requiring a request to the server to get the same data that is already in the datasource.

One thing I tried was attaching the class to the button in the cancel event handler but at that point the button doesn't exist:

```
onCancel: function (e) {
    // NB: following does not work - submit button doesn't exist until after this function is called
    const currentRow = $(e.container).closest("tr");
    currentRow.find(".k-grid-submit").prepend("<span class='k-icon k-i-redo' style='color: blue'></span>");
```

Another suggestion was to [set the command text using jQuery](https://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-command-icon-disappears#7NPF1wreP0WjfLLzvuuxvw):

```
col.Command(c => c.Custom("History").Click("showHistory")).Text($"<span class='k-icon k-i-reorder'></span> History");
```

Which would be great except the mvvm approach to defining the grid doesn't appear to provide an option for binding the button `text` property. Currently I'm using the workaround of refreshing the datasource from the server but it would be helpful to be able to resolve this without a server round-trip.

Answer (score 0):

Because the cancel button its a runtime element try this and remove the event cancel.

```
$(document).on('click', 'cancelButtonSelector', function(){
// apply the icon to $(this)
});
```